# What is the use case of the immutable objects

Tags: python

What is the use case of immutable types/objects like tuple in python.

```
Tuple('hello')
 ('h','i')
```

Where we can use the not changeable sequences.

Comment: Have you never had an object that you didn't need to change?  If the object is immutable there is no need to define methods which resize it at runtime.  Thus the object becomes more light weight in memory and speed.

Comment: when you want to use something that cannot be modified i,e immutable. For example how would you store multiple elements as keys of a dict in a mutable structure?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm not sure I follow your `dict` `key` example.

Comment: @Matt, how would you use  `1,2,3` three separate ints as a single key for a dict? Would it be good if your structure i.e tuple that they were stored in were mutable?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham oh I see what you're saying.  In order for an object to truly be `hashable` it needs a static representation.

Comment: @Matt, yes, it would not be good if your objects hash value changed after you added it as a key in your dict

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think this is another good reason to use immutability.

Comment: Frankly, I almost wish tuples were called frozenlist, to match frozenset and frozendict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutable objects will make life simpler in many cases. They are especially applicable for value types, where objects don't have an identity so they can be easily replaced. And they can make concurrent programming way safer and cleaner (most of the notoriously hard to find concurrency bugs are ultimately caused by mutable state shared between threads). However, for large and/or complex objects, creating a new copy of the object for every single change can be very costly and/or tedious. And for objects with a distinct identity, changing an existing objects is much more simple and intuitive than creating a new, modified copy of it.

Answer (score 3):

One common use case is the list of (unnamed) arguments to a function.

```
In [1]: def foo(*args):
   ...:     print(type(args))
   ...:     

In [2]: foo(1,2,3)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically, tuples are semantically different to lists.

When you have a list, you have something that is... a list. Of items of some sort. And therefore can have items added or removed to it.

A tuple, on the other hand, is a set of values in a given order. It just happens to be one value that is made up of more than one value. A composite value.

For example. Say you have a point. X, Y. You could have a class called Point, but that class would have a dictionary to store its attributes. A point is only two values which are, most of the time, used together. You don't need the flexibility or the cost of a dictionary for storing named attributes, you can use a tuple instead.

```
myPoint = 70, 2
```

Points are always X and Y. Always 2 values. They are not lists of numbers. They are two values in which the order of a value matters.

Another example of tuple usage. A function that creates links from a list of tuples. The tuples must be the `href` and then the label of the link. Fixed order. Order that has meaning.

```
def make_links(*tuples):
    return "".join('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % t for t in tuples)

make_links(
    ("//google.com", "Google"),
    ("//stackoveflow.com", "Stack Overflow")
)
```

So the reason tuples don't change is because they are supposed to be one single value. You can only assign the whole thing at once.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good resource that describes the difference between tuples and lists, and the reasons for using each: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2001-September/008888.html

The main reason outlined in that link is that tuples are immutable and less extensive than say, lists. This makes them useful only in certain situations, but if those situations can be identified, tuples take up much less resources.